# On-Chain NFT: How to store a pixel image on the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

I have a finished art project and I am looking for a way to store the data on-chain. Like deafbeef for example. The source of my generated 6x6 pixel images are pictures, so I cannot recreate them by code. I guess I have to store their raw data in some form on-chain.

I am new to blockchain stuff. I know that tokens are stored on the chain, I have minted some artworks on hen and opensea, but I generally do not understand how it all works in the background.

Can you recommend some well explained tutorials or articles on this topic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why they need to be stored on-chain?
Normally images are stored off chain to reduce the cost of transactions.

You can upload the image onto ipfs via pinata and then create a json file that point to it and upload that through pinata as well. The tokenURI would then be that json file.

For example,

```
TokenURI=ipfs://<json_file_hash>"
```

Then in your JSON file:

```json
{
    "image": "<image_file_hash>"
}
```

Comment: The reason to store on-chain is to ensure the longevity of the NFT image (artwork) asset and in turn, allow the token to hold its "value". With off-chain assets, there's always a risk that the NFT metadata will refresh and try to access a resource that may no longer exist... ie the NFT metadata API or image asset bucket could be taken offline...